# How to write grouping algorithm that groups items in dataset by having 3 or more similar properties

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typescript, cluster-analysis

I'm building a tool for my client which groups keywords together based on the top 10 Google search URLs. The keyword is represented as a JavaScript object containing an array of URLs. The grouping criteria is that **two keywords** belong to the same group if they have **3 or more URLs in common**. Also, there should be **no keyword duplication** in generated groups and the total number of generated groups is not predefined before the grouping. I would appreciate any advice on the *logic* part of this problem, thanks!

So far I managed to develop the algorithm provided below, but it still makes duplicates and doesn't group keyword 100% right (some keywords should be in the same group but they are not).

```
function makeKeywordGroupsNew(results: Result[], uid: string): Group[] {
  let dataset = results;
  let groups: any[] = [];

  // loop thru all records in dataset
  dataset.forEach((current: Result) => {
    // initialize the group with the current keyword in it
    const group = { volume: 0, items: [current] };
    // remove the current keyword from the dataset
    dataset = dataset.filter(el => el.keyword !== current.keyword);
    // loop thru the new dataset and push the other keyword into the group if it has >=3 urls in common with current keyword
    dataset.forEach((other: Result) => {
      const urlsInCommon = _.intersection(current.urls, other.urls);
      if (urlsInCommon.length >= 3) {
        group.items.push(other);
      }
    });

    // sum the keyword volumes to form the group volume - not important for the core logic
    // @ts-ignore
    group.volume = _.sum(group.items.map(item => item.volume));
    // sort keywords in the formed group by volume - not important for the core logic
    // @ts-ignore
    group.items = group.items
      .sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.volume < b.volume) return 1;
        if (a.volume > b.volume) return -1;
        return 0;
      })
      .map(el => el.keyword);
    // add the newly formed group to the groups array (the result)
    groups.push(group);
  });

  // exclude the groups with only one keyword inside
  groups = groups.filter(group => group.items.length > 1);
  // delete keyword duplicates inside of the group
  groups = groups.map(group => ({ ...group, items: _.uniq(group.items) }));
  // form the correct result object shape - not important for the core logic
  return groups.map(group => ({
    uid,
    main: group.items[0],
    keywords: group.items.slice(1, group.length),
    volume: group.volume
  }));
}
```

I expected the output of [input.json](https://pastebin.com/ZiAsXhKP) to be [output.csv](https://pastebin.com/DQKZRXSr), but my solution either puts fewer keywords in a group or makes the wrong groups.

Comment: Say keywords 1, 13 and 47 share the same 3 urls [a,b,c].  Your code will build groups of [1,13,47] and then [13,47] - is that desired behavior?  It's really hard to eyeball your dataset and expected results can you pare that down to something that shows the problem within say 10 records?

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible problems could be the way you are filtering the `dataset` array which is being looped through and being filtered inside its own loop. You can filter the `dataset` and remove the current  keyword and put it in another variable and then foreach on that instead of modifying `dataset` itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at the result, I don't think this is correct because this results in 135 "groups" and the expected number is 87, and the original code produces 88

I think your issue is right at the top of your code

```
  let dataset = results;
  let groups: any[] = [];

  dataset.forEach((current: Result) => {
    const group = { volume: 0, items: [current] };
    dataset = dataset.filter(el => el.keyword !== current.keyword);
```

You're mutating `dataset` inside the `dataSet.forEach` function

I think that needs to be

```
  //let dataset = results; remove this
  let groups: any[] = [];

  results.forEach((current: Result) => {
    const group = { volume: 0, items: [current] };
    const dataset = results.filter(el => el.keyword !== current.keyword);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified into a single `reduce` fn invocation to avoid side-effects and confusion:

```
const out = data.reduce((acc, current, index) => {
  const maybeGroup = acc.findIndex(
    el => _.intersection(current.urls, el.urls).length > 3
  );
  if (maybeGroup !== -1 || maybeGroup === 0) {
    if(!acc[maybeGroup].searches.includes(current.keyword)) {
      acc[maybeGroup].searches.push(current.keyword);
      return acc;
    }
    return acc;
  } else {
    acc.push({
      mainKeyword: current.keyword,
      searches: [],
      urls: current.urls
    });
    return acc;
  }
}, []);
console.log(out.map(x => _.pick(x, ['mainKeyword', 'searches'])))
```

This ignores the counting & sorting logic of course but that can be easily added into the existing code.